# Lenses that pixeliate incoming light

Tags: visible-light, lenses, discrete

Is it possible to make a lens that 'pixelates' the light passing through it? I imagine a pair of glasses, that when put on, turn the world into a grid of discrete pixels, each having, or appearing to have, a singular color value.

How would one create/model this?

Edit: For an example,

[image: xP]

Instead of seeing the image above, you'd see the following image if you look through the lens

[image: pixelated xP]

Comment: Are you talking about laser speckle? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speckle_pattern

Comment: But you wouldn't consider a "screen door" as "optic" ?

Comment: A 2D [lenslet array](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=lenslet+array&tbm=isch) seems relevant.

Comment: @Qmechanic Yes! Something like that, as lenses in glasses. How should those individual lenses be designed/shaped in order to produce the desired effect? How many can I pack into a given area?

Comment: @thunder2709 Do you wish to somehow use a combination of lenses to see the world like [this image](http://i.imgur.com/31a5Zgl.jpg) instead of clear and sharp?

Basically you want to blur your vision and then distinctly pixelate it?

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha That is correct.

Comment: It looks like what you're trying to do is to make a lower resololution image.

Comment: @JQK Essentially yes, a low res version of reality

Comment: @Qmechanic is this question eligible for re-opening now?

Comment: Hi @PeeyushKushwaha: It is preferred that the Phys.SE community reviewers (rather than moderators) decide whether or not to re-open. Note that any new edit automatically propels the post into the review queue.

Comment: I did not know that edits place questions on hold into the review queue. Thanks!